# При компиляции проекта в Xcode, выдает ошибку "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, xcode, компиляция

Сначала Xcode жаловался на отсутствие несколько библиотек в проекте. Но я их восстановил. Сейчас я уперся в эту ошибку

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use v to see invocation)

и не могу понять, что мне делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

не найдена библиотека fmode_iphones

**Обновлено из коментария**

То что библиотека "есть" не означает что линкер знает где она находится. он там выше ругается, что не нашел большого числа папок, которые тоже видимо указаны в свойствах проекта, которые ему указали в качестве путей поиска для либ и фреймворков. в проекте пути поиска прописаны и я не знаю как Вы добавили библиотеку в проект. Судя по ошибке линкера вы добавили ее в проект каким-то способом и линкер знает что ему надо с ней линковаться, но он ее не нашел

Comment: Дело в том, что библиотека fmode и файл "fmode_iphones" на который ссылается Xcode тоже есть.

Comment: То что она есть не означает что линкер знает где она есть.
он там выше ругается что целой кучи папок не нашел которые ему указали в качестве путей поиска для либ и фреймворков.
в проекте пути поиска прописаны и я не знаю как Вы добавили библиотеку в проект.

Судя по ошибке линкера вы добавили ее в проект каким-то способом  и линкер знает что ему надо с ней линковаться, но он ее не нашел

Comment: @DmitryA., дополните, пожалуйста, ваш ответ информацией из комментария (нажав [edit]).

Answer (score 0):

Провертье что указанная библиотека присутствует в настройках таргета в секции "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" и в Build Phases в секции "Link Binary With Libraries"